# kotlin Corountines and live data integrations error in find class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<

Tags: android, android-livedata, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am facing live data and coroutines problems in my project. I am getting following error

> kotlin.coroutines.Continuation> p1) {
>                                                                          ^
>          symbol:   class BookJson 
>          location: class BookClientHelper

I have added co-routines in my project recently. I am getting above error. I have kapt,ktx and coroutines dependency in my gradle.

My project build gradle looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mine.bookkeeper"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = [
                    "room.schemaLocation":"$projectDir/schemas".toString(),
                    "room.incremental":"true",
                    "room.expandProjection":"true"]
        }
    }

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'

implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

def room_version = "2.2.3"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:2.1.0-alpha04"

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"


// optional - RxJava support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.1'
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.1"



implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3'

}
```

1. Why it is not able to find normal class file ?
2. is it dependency problem or gradle plugin problem ?

Little bit new to kotlin. A little description will help me to move ahead with these components

Thanks in advance

Comment: ok just do a little thing that take 100 of hours then let me know, remove the double quotations from dependency whose versions are not set to variable i.e  your liveData's dependency put them in single quotation , other as well..

Comment: sure i will do this. can please describes ? why need we do this ?

Comment: yeah you only use double quotation when you are setting versions to some variables if not then its better to keep them in single quotation